# Call variable from outside of function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How can I call `$attach_id` from outside of a function?

```
function kv_handle_attachment($file_handler, $post_id, $set_thu = false) {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file_handler, $post_id);
    return $attach_id;
}

echo $attach_id;
```

Comment: by calling the function?

Comment: `$attach_id = kv_handle_attachment(...)`

Comment: @iainn  showing this error "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/demo/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=hotel_info_ajaxinsert"

Comment: @Syn00123 your file permission issue or file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you get value from function then you need to call this function this is your code, this is demo code which return 12

```
<?php
function kv_handle_attachment($file_handler, $post_id)
{
    return 12;
}

$attach_id = kv_handle_attachment('1', 12);
echo $attach_id;
```

so update your code like this

```
<?php
function kv_handle_attachment($file_handler, $post_id, $set_thu = false)
{
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload($file_handler, $post_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

so call your function

```
$attach_id = kv_handle_attachment($file_handler, $post_id);
```

or this is more clear option

```
$attach_id = kv_handle_attachment($yourdatahere); //$yourdatahere update as your parameter which you need to send but your first 2 parameter is required so need to send this must but not empty 
echo $attach_id;
```

Comment: check my update answer which return 12 so i think function call ok and your next code not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a global variable.

```
function kv_handle_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {
    global $attach_id;
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
    return $attach_id;
}

global $attach_id;
echo $attach_id;
```

Comment: The use of Global variables is *strongly* discouraged.